# R accessing text in GRID.text

Tags: r, plot

Is there any way to access the actual text stored in the GRID.text reference?

I now i can modify it by using grid.edit()

but say the GRID.text is a number - and I want to normalise that number after the plot is made (since the function that creates the plot does a lot of calculations).

A small example of what I want to do:

```
library('grid')
grid.newpage()
grid.text("100",name='t1')
```

In this example I would like to extract the number 100 - so i can modify it (say devide it by 5) and then use edit to modify the plot:

```
grid.edit(gPath='t1',label='the modified number')
```

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do

```
grid.get('t1')$label
```

Comment: That was excatly what I was looking for. Thanks!